# Installing real-time kernel on EndeavourOS

Tags: kernel, compiling, real-time, endeavouros

I'm trying to install a real-time kernel on EndeavourOS without any success. I tried different method... the first one, downloading it from yay repository as suggested by the Arch Linux wiki but compiling never ends; then, I tried to download first the PKGBUILD and then compiling it later but the result was the same; finally, I've found a webpage on the Linux Foundation's site about PREEMPT_RT patch and I followed the instruction... first, download the kernel (in my case, 6.0[EndeavourOS already mount a 6.0.2 version, but real-time patch was not upgraded yet to this... that's why I downloaded the '6.0' one and the related rt-patch '6.0' to match them perfectly]). In a first attempt to this last method, I tried mixing the 6.0.3 version of the linux kernel with the 6.0 rt-patch. Maybe I have to remove something of the old attempts? And how I have to do it? Arch (and linux in general) is a new thing for me (I know a little better fedora but arch is more performant for my purpose).

Terminal returns this:

```
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

and this is returned for different stuff but it's long to show here.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess to have found the problem... basically, the directory's name where there's the source had some spaces in it (it seems it is 'akward' for the compiler a name written with spaces... so, I changed the directory's name avoiding them). Then, I gave the command 'make config' for starting the configuration file for the kernel. It seems it works.